# Is there an easy way to make a variable in a reloading event not reset? discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, export, node-modules

Hey is there anyone that could help me with importing/exporting between files?
I am making a discord bot and I want to make it so the bot "counts" in a specified channel. In the channel "counting" I want the bot to check every message and if the message is 1 I want it to react to it with an emote and then I want it so that `nextNumber` adds 1 to itself so it becomes 2. Then on the next message I want it to be so that if `nextNumber` is 2 it adds one to itself etc and if it's something else than the correct number it says "Oh no wrong number" and resets to 1.

So basically folder structure is like this:
TechniLogBot (main folder)
mybot.js (in main folder)
-events (folder in main folder)
--message.js (in events folder)

My message.js loads each time a message is sent in the server. I have 3 variables that when in the message.js resets everytime a message is sent. I don't want them to obviously. This bot is supposed to "count". So what I have done is placed the 3 variables in my main js file which is mybot.js and tried to export them to my message.js and there they should be updated and exported back to mybot.js and so on.

The code I have now is:

//mybot.js

```
let countStatStart = 0;
let nextNumberStart = 1;
let countRestartStart = true;
module.exports={
  countStatStart,
  nextNumberStart,
  countRestartStart  
}
```

//message.js

```
const myBotModule = require('./mybot'); //I have tried ('../mybot') & ('TechniLogBot/mybot')

let countStat = myBotModule.countStatStart;
let nextNumber = myBotModule.nextNumberStart;
let countRestart = myBotModule.countRestartStart;
console.log(countStat, nextNumber, countRestart);
```

The issue is that when it produces undefined. What am I doing wrong and also how do I easiest import them back to mybot to avoid being reset? And is there an easier way to do all this?  I heard of global variables and that you shouldn't use them but I'm not so advanced in javascript.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A simple Code would be something like this: (Not quite sure what your question is though....)

```
let countStatStart = 0;
let nextNumberStart = 1;


const countchannel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === 'Countchannelid')
if (message.channel.id === countchannel){ //Check if message is in specific channel
   if (message.content === nextNumberStart){
      countStatStart = countStatStart + 1
      nextNumberStart = nextNumberStart + 1 //progress the counting
   }else{
   countStatStart = 0
   nextNumberStart = 1 //Reset all the stats
   msg.author.reply('Oops Wrong Number')}
}else{ 
return; 
}
```

In my projects, i usually keep some simple variables and consts in my main js file. The import and export commands make it much more complicated.